# count not null columns out of specific list of columns and then compare in where clause for each row

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join, where-clause

Table structure:

[Table Structure http://imagebin.org/index.php?mode=image&id=238883](http://imagebin.org/index.php?mode=image&id=238883)

I want to fetch data from both the tables which satisfy some of the conditions like

```
    WHERE batch='2009', sex='male',course='B.Tech', branch='cs', xth_percent>60, 
     x2percent>60, gradpercent>60 and (if ranktype='other' ) then 
     no._of_not_null_semester>number elseifranktype='Leet') then 
     no._of_not_null_semester>number-2
```

sem 1-8 contains percentage for 8 semesters, and I want to filter results for each student if they have cleared 3 semesters or 4 semester i.e. not null values out of 8 values

```
 no._of_not_null_semester
```

needs to be calculated, it is not a part of database, need help with that as well.

Required Query

```
             SELECT * FROM student_test 
                      INNER JOIN master_test ON student_test.id=master_test.id 
                      WHERE sex='male' and batch='2009' and course='B.Tech' 
                      and xthpercent>60 and x2percent>60 and 
                      WHEN ranktype='Leet' THEN 
                              SUM(CASE WHEN sem1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0) >2
                      ELSE 
                             SUM(CASE WHEN sem1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                 WHEN sem2 S NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem3 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem4 IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0
                                  WHEN sem5 IS NOT NULL THEN 1  ELSE 0) >4
```

Comment: Please show the exact schema of your tables. Do the tables have a 1-1 relationship?

Comment: Yes tables have 1-1 relationship, and the two tables have only single common column i.e id

Comment: As well as the schemas, it would also help to see an example comprising of data samples and the expected output.

Comment: Is semester a 3rd table? Please post your table structure e.g. `show create table student_test`

Comment: http://imagebin.org/238883


here is the image for table structures

there are basically two problems
I can't sort the data based upon no. of semester not null out of sem1-sem8

other is

if a student has ranktype='leet' than no.of semesters not null required is 2 less than no.of_semester not_null for other students

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the structure you can't use `COUNT` to achieve this.

One way to solve the problem would be to create a semester table which would contain a row for each finished semester for each student. This would have a foreign key pointing to `test_student.id` and you could use `COUNT(semester.id)`

If that is an option for you, it would be the best solution.

**EDIT:**

Check this out, didn't test the query but should work generally
I decided to do the math in the select itself to prevent calculating the same thing twice.
The `HAVING` conditions are applied after your result is ready to deliver, just before a `LIMIT`.
In terms of speed optimization you could try and move the sSum block into the WHERE condition just like you had it before. Probably it doesn't make much of a difference

`SUM()` does not work because it is an aggregate function which summarizes values in a column

I did some changes to your query in addition:

- don't SELECT `*`, select specific fields and add a table identifier. ( in this case I used the aliases `s` for `student_test` AND `m` for `master_test` )
- you put `s.batch = '2009'` into single quotes - if the field `batch` is an integer field, you should use `s.batch = 2009`, which would prevent MySQL from casting every single row to string to be able to compare it (`int = int` much faster than `cast(int as varchar) = varchar`) same about the other numeric values in your table

The Query:

```
SELECT
    s.id,
    s.sex,
    s.course,
    s.branch,
    ( 
        IF ( m.sem1 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem3 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem4 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem5 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem6 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem7 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( m.sem8 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0 )
    ) AS sSum
FROM
    student_test s
        INNER JOIN master_test m ON m.id = s.id
WHERE
    s.sex = 'male'
    AND
    s.batch = '2009' # I dont see this field in your database diagram!?
    AND
    s.course = 'B.Tech'
    AND
    m.xthpercent > 60
    AND
    m.x2percent > 60
HAVING
    (
        m.ranktype = 'OTHER'
        AND
        sSum > 4
    )
    OR
    (
        m.ranktype = 'LEET'
        AND
        sSum > 2
    )
```

If you're generally interested in learning database design and usage I found an very interesting opportunity for you.
Stanford University offers a free database class "Introduction to databases". This is free and will cost you approx. 2 hours a week for 3 weeks, final exam included.

https://class2go.stanford.edu/db/Winter2013/preview/

Comment: row for each clear semester, for each student????. wouldn't be that very lengthy, I've a record of 3,000 students increasing by 600 each year.

Comment: this are no numbers a dbms would even start getting warm

Comment: I have the golden rule: If a quite simple query is not solvable without breaking a leg, something is wrong in the database design. Still I'll think about a solution which would not change the table structure - it might be possible but probably quite complex and hard to modify

Comment: I accept that Design might be wrong no doubt, I'm still a learner :)
But modifying the database might be more painfull at the moment.

Comment: the query you just posted above is looking quite good - does it solve your problem?

Comment: no that's the problem and i need help with this query only..... sql says 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHEN ranktype='OTHER' THEN SUM(CASE WHEN sem1 IS ' at line 5

Comment: thanks for trying :), but somehow sSum is coming out same for all students i.e 8

Comment: And your suggestions are really useful, just one thing wrong i.e Y i'm getting sSum =8 for all rows which I'm getting in result(probably filtered by other conditions)

Comment: For further clarification I'm attaching an image here...... 
http://imagebin.org/238900
for first row sSum should be 3, for next row it should be 4, for next it should be 2 but it's 8 for all in output

And yes I Appreciate your try.....thanks :)

Comment: If i try the if condition seperately on 2nd table i got correct results but not in join conditn
SELECT m.id,
              m.sem1,
              m.sem2,
m.sem3,
m.sem4,
m.sem5,
m.sem6,
m.sem7,
m.sem8, ( 
        IF ( ceil(m.sem1)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem2)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem3)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem4)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem5)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem6)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem7)>0, 1, 0 ) +
        IF ( ceil(m.sem8)>0, 1, 0 )
    ) AS sSum FROM master_test m HAVING sSum>1 ORDER BY `sSum` ASC

http://imagebin.org/239005

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
s.id,
s.sex,
s.course,
s.deptt,
m1.id,
m1.xthpercent,
m1.x2percent,
m1.sem1,
m1.sem2,
m1.sem3,
m1.ranktype,
m1.sem4,
m1.sem5,
m1.sem6,
m1.sem7,
m1.sem8,
m1.sSum
FROM
student_test s
    INNER JOIN(SELECT m.id,
                      m.xthpercent,
                      m.x2percent,
                      m.sem1,
                      m.sem2,
                      m.sem3,
                      m.ranktype,
                      m.sem4,
                      m.sem5,
                      m.sem6,
                      m.sem7,
                      m.sem8,
                      (    IF ( ceil(m.sem1)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem2)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem3)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem4)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem5)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem6)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem7)>0, 1, 0 ) +
                           IF ( ceil(m.sem8)>0, 1, 0 )
                      ) AS sSum FROM master_test m 
                                WHERE m.xthpercent>60 and 
                                      m.x2percent>60 
                               HAVING (m.ranktype='Leet' AND sSum>2 )
                               OR
                              (m.ranktype != 'Leet') AND sSum>4 )
   as m1 ON m1.id = s.id

 WHERE 
 s.sex='Male'
 and
 s.course='B.Tech'
 and 
 s.deptt='ELE'
```

This is the query finally I'm using, Love that query :)

Comment: suggestions are invited still .